# (sed beginner) replace characters in an env variable

Tags: linux, shell, sed

How can I replace caracters "on the fly" when using sed ?
Example :

I want this command to be executed :
    /bin/sed 's/HOSTNAME=.*/HOSTNAME=**server_domain_com**/g' /etc/sysconfig/network

Instead of this one :
    /bin/sed 's/HOSTNAME=.*/HOSTNAME=**server.domain.com**/g' /etc/sysconfig/network

the string "server.domain.com" is contained in a env variable and I would like to replace the dots by an underscore before replacing the appropriate line in /etc/sysconfig/network.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with bash substitution too:

```
/bin/sed -i "s/HOSTNAME=.*/HOSTNAME=${HOSTNAME//./_}/g" /etc/sysconfig/network
```

The `//` instructs it to change all occurences (like g in sed). Do not forget the `-i` flag to actually change the file, not just print it.

Answer (score 7):

```
HOSTNAME=$(echo $HOSTNAME | sed s/from/to/g)
```